# Linkedin company page post not working via linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

Authentication and profile post posting working well when post in company page give below error

```
Response: 500 Internal Server Error

{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Internal service error",
  "requestId": "DBF51M03PY",
  "status": 500,
  "timestamp": 1532353548757
}
```

is there any change in API? Anyone face same issue? Same code working 2-3 days ago.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/" + companyPageId + "/shares?format=json
```

Comment: which type of authentication you are using oauth 2.0 or oauth 1.0 ? if you are using oauth 1.0 you need to update the authentication to oauth 2.0 .

Comment: I thought oauth 2.0

Comment: i am also using same api in my project but its working fine . make sure that company with id exist or not .

Comment: It's already come via API with correct company list. can you share Linkedin share REST API URL?

Comment: uri = URI.parse("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/#{company_id}/shares?oauth2_access_token=#{token}&format=json")

Comment: thanks :) let me check